# Uso do equals e herança

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança, equals

Eu tenho uma classe pai e nela eu tenho um `equals` e tenho outras classes filhas dessa minha classe pai e nelas eu quero sobrescrever o `equals` para comparar atributos particulares dessas classes filhas porem também quero fazer uso do `equals` do meu pai para comparar os atributos herdados pela minhas filhas, como faria isso sem ter que reescrever tudo?

```
public class Pai {

   String nome;

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      Pai other = (Pai) obj;
      return(this.nome.equals(other.nome);
   }

}

public class Filha extends Pai {
        int atributoEspecifico`;

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            // como comparo aquele atributo do meu pai também?
            Filha other = (Filha) obj;
            return this.atributoEspecifico == other.atributoEspecifico;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Você pode por um trecho que exemplifique isto?

Comment: claro, vou postar.

Comment: coloca um trecho, para melhor entendimento

Comment: Você tentou comparar o atributo da classe pai e não deu certo? Tentou `return this.atributoEspecifico == other.atributoEspecifico && this.nome.equals(other.nome)`? O `nome` é visível em todo o *package*, então ele deveria ser visível na filha a não ser que a filha esteja em outro pacote. Experimentou usar `proteceted` no `nome`? Se fizer isto aí se não me engano terá que acessar com `super`.

Comment: @bigown Acho que o ponto-chave aqui é "sem ter que reescrever tudo". Mesmo que o `nome` esteja acessível na subclasse, não seria uma boa ideia repetir a lógica do `equals` se o que o AP quer é reutilizá-la (em outros casos poderia ser). P.S. usei a referência no seu [comentário na resposta deletada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41307/uso-do-equals-e-heran%c3%a7a#comment81515_41309) na minha resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Esse é um caso de uso típico para o [`super`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html):

1. Compare as instâncias usando os critérios da superclasse;
2. Se tudo estiver ok, compare *também* usando os critérios da própria classe.

Exemplo de código (sem tratamento de erros, como por exemplo verificar se o argumento pertence a classe certa):

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if ( !super.equals(obj) )
        return false;

    Filha other = (Filha) obj;
    return this.atributoEspecifico == other.atributoEspecifico;
}
```

Note que isso funciona em qualquer profundidade: se você criar uma classe `Neta` que herda de `Filha`, e chamar o `super.equals` nela também, serão aplicados os critérios de `Pai`, `Filha` e `Neta`, nessa ordem.